# Не отображается .obj при загрузке в браузер. Подключил three.js, OBJLoader2.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, obj

помогите, пожалуйста - в console.log - показывает, что .obj загрузилось успешно...Первый раз пытаюсь разобраться с three.js, добавить модель, может ошибка какая-то банальная...попробовал на нескольких моделях .obj. Пока создавал свои кубики/сферы - всё работало. Вот код

```
import { OrbitControls } from "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { OBJLoader2 } from "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js";

window.onload = function () {
  // Присвоили значения канвасу
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  let height = window.innerHeight;
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.setAttribute("width", width);
  canvas.setAttribute("height", height);

  let ball = { rotationY: 0.01 };
  // GUI
  // let gui = new dat.GUI();
  // gui.add(ball, "rotationY").min(-0.2).max(0.2).step(0.001);
  // Рендерер
  let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
  // Сцена
  let scene = new THREE.Scene();
  // Камера
  let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 5000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
  // Свет
  let light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
  scene.add(light);

  // instantiate a loader
  const loader = new OBJLoader2();

  // load a resource
  loader.load(
    // resource URL
    "./obj/cube.obj",
    // "./obj/rx8.obj",
    // called when resource is loaded
    function (object) {
      scene.add(object);
    },
    // called when loading is in progresses
    function (xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function (error) {
      console.log("An error happened");
    }
  );
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

// instantiate the loader
//   {
//     const objLoader = new OBJLoader2();
//     objLoader.load("./obj/cube.obj", (root) => {
//       scene.add(root);
//     });
//     // objLoader.onError(console.log("ERROR"));
//   }
// };
```

Comment: Модель может быть очень маленькой. Модель может не попадать в поле зрения камеры. Без живого примера трудно что-то конкретное сказать. P.S. Рекомендуемый формат для three.js - glTF.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду пробовать